# Nvidia card is not recognized by xorg

Tags: ubuntu, x11, nvidia, proprietary-drivers, optimus

I have laptop with both discrete (GTX 1050) and integrated graphic cards. `lspci` gives this:

```
▶ lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D" 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
```

I've installed the latest proprietary nvidia driver. `nvidia-smi` output

```
▶ nvidia-smi

Fri Apr 19 20:54:39 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   40C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**The problem:** nvidia card isn't recognized by xorg. I'm using Ubuntu 19.04, but it's doesn't seems to be the ubuntu-specific problem. `glxinfo` shows:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

`nvidia-settings` doesn't work properly:

```
▶ nvidia-settings

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


(nvidia-settings:7956): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 21:01:38.477: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 21:01:38.481: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 21:01:38.481: PRIME: is it supported? yes
```

[image: nvidia-settings window]

`xrandr --listproviders` doesn't see nvidia card:

```
▶ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x48 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 5 associated providers: 0 name:Intel
```

I tried to follow [this](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/howto-set-up-prime-with-nvidia-proprietary-driver/40225) guide to configure xorg and setup PRIME output, but it didn't changed the output of `glxinfo`, and currently I'm not using any additional xorg configuration. I've enabled drm by`/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-drm.conf`:

```
options nvidia_drm modeset=1
```

`/etc/modules`:

```
nvidia
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
nvidia_drm
```

By the way, my xorg log:

```
[    28.879]     X.Org X Server 1.20.4    X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    28.879] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-143-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[    28.879] Current Operating System: Linux danm-book 5.0.0-13-generic #14-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 15 14:59:14 UTC 2019 x86_64
[    28.879] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.0.0-13-generic root=UUID=a61fca93-69d6-4e26-9b2c-674736f3d449 ro pti=off spectre_v2=off l1tf=off nospec_store_bypass_disable no_stf_barrier quiet splash nouveau.runpm=0 rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau vt.handoff=1
[    28.879] Build Date: 03 April 2019  09:03:57AM
[    28.879] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1ubuntu3 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    28.879] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[    28.879]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    28.880] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    28.880] (==) Log file: "/home/danm/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Apr 19 20:29:21 2019
[    28.880] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    28.882] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    28.882] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[    28.882] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[    28.882] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    28.883] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    28.883] (**) |   |-->Device "card0"
[    28.883] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    28.883] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    28.883] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    28.883] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[    28.883] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[    28.883] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[    28.883] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    28.883]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[    28.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    28.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[    28.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    28.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    28.884] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[    28.884] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    28.884] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    28.884] (II) Loader magic: 0x55c10a745020
[    28.884] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    28.884]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    28.884]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[    28.884]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[    28.884]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[    28.885] (++) using VT number 2

[    28.889] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_32
[    28.890] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[    28.892] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 12 paused 0
[    28.892] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[    28.893] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 13 paused 0
[    28.895] (**) OutputClass "nvidia" ModulePath extended to "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    28.895] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" ModulePath extended to "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia-418/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    28.895] (**) OutputClass "Nvidia Prime" setting /dev/dri/card0 as PrimaryGPU
[    28.897] (--) PCI: (0@0:2:0) 8086:3e9b:1043:1fc0 rev 0, Mem @ 0xa2000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    28.897] (--) PCI:*(1@0:0:0) 10de:1c8d:1043:1fc0 rev 161, Mem @ 0xa3000000/16777216, 0x90000000/268435456, 0xa0000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[    28.898] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    28.899] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[    28.901] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    28.901]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[    28.901]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[    28.901] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[    28.902] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[    28.905] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    28.905]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.99.917
[    28.905]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    28.905]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[    28.905] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[    28.905] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    28.905] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[    28.905] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[    28.905] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[    28.906] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20181204
[    28.906] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20180925-2 (Andreas Boll <aboll@debian.org>)
[    28.906] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[    28.926] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[    28.927] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics
[    28.927] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2; using a maximum of 4 threads
[    28.927] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    28.927] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[    28.927] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[    28.927] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    28.927] (**) intel(0): Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
[    28.928] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[    28.938] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Output DP1 has no monitor section
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Enabled output DP1
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI2 has no monitor section
[    28.938] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI2
[    28.939] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[    28.939] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[    28.939] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[    28.939] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 3840x2160 on pipe 0
[    28.939] (==) intel(0): TearFree disabled
[    28.939] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    28.939] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[    28.939] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[    28.939] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[    28.939] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[    28.939] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    28.939] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    28.939] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[    28.939] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[    28.939] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[    28.939] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[    28.942] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Coffeelake (gen9) backend
[    28.942] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    28.942] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    28.943] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    28.944] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    28.944] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    28.944] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    28.944] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    28.944] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    28.944] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    28.944] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[    28.944] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[    28.944] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[    28.944] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[    28.945] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[    28.945] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[    28.946] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    28.946] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[    28.946] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[    28.946] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[    28.947] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[    28.947] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[    28.947] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[    28.947] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[    28.948] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[    28.948] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[    28.948] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    28.948] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    28.949] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[    28.949] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[    28.949] (II) Initializing extension Present
[    28.949] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[    28.949] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[    28.949] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[    28.950] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    28.950] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[    28.950] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[    28.950] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    29.050] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[    29.050] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[    29.050] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    29.051] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[    29.051] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[    29.051] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[    29.066] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 3840x2160@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[    29.073] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 1016 x 571
[    29.128] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[    29.128] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.128] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    29.129] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    29.131] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    29.131]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.28.2
[    29.131]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    29.131]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    29.131] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    29.132] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67 fd 24 paused 0
[    29.132] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    29.132] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    29.132] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.135] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.135] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    29.136] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[    29.136] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[    29.136] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    29.136] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.136] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.136] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.136] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.164] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.164] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    29.164] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus Wireless Radio Control (/dev/input/event7)
[    29.164] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.164] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus Wireless Radio Control'
[    29.165] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event7 13:71 fd 27 paused 0
[    29.165] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: always reports core events
[    29.165] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    29.165] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.166] (II) event7  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.166] (II) event7  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device is a keyboard
[    29.166] (II) event7  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device removed
[    29.166] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/input/input7/event7"
[    29.166] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus Wireless Radio Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    29.166] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.166] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.166] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.166] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.167] (II) event7  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.167] (II) event7  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device is a keyboard
[    29.167] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[    29.167] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.167] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.168] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    29.168] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.168] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    29.168] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event2 13:66 fd 28 paused 0
[    29.168] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    29.168] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    29.168] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.169] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.169] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    29.169] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    29.169] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2/event2"
[    29.170] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    29.170] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.170] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.170] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.170] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.170] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.170] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    29.171] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    29.171] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.171] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    29.171] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event1 13:65 fd 29 paused 0
[    29.172] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    29.172] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    29.172] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.172] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.172] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    29.172] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    29.172] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[    29.172] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    29.172] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.172] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.172] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.172] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.173] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.173] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    29.174] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD (/dev/input/event15)
[    29.175] (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.175] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD'
[    29.175] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event15 13:79 fd 30 paused 0
[    29.175] (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: always reports core events
[    29.175] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event15"
[    29.175] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.177] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.177] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device is a keyboard
[    29.177] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device removed
[    29.177] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input18/event15"
[    29.177] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    29.177] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.177] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.177] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.177] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.178] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.178] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device is a keyboard
[    29.179] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad (/dev/input/event6)
[    29.179] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[    29.179] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad'
[    29.191] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event6 13:70 fd 31 paused 0
[    29.191] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: always reports core events
[    29.191] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    29.191] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.192] (II) event6  - ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    29.193] (II) event6  - ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[    29.193] (II) event6  - ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: device removed
[    29.193] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-2/i2c-ELAN1300:00/0018:04F3:3057.0001/input/input10/event6"
[    29.193] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[    29.195] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    29.195] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    29.195] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    29.195] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    29.195] (II) event6  - ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[    29.196] (II) event6  - ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[    29.197] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN1300:00 04F3:3057 Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    29.197] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.197] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.197] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[    29.197] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.197] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.198] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[    29.198] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.198] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.198] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[    29.198] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.198] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.198] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[    29.198] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.198] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.198] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event12)
[    29.198] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.198] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.199] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event13)
[    29.199] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.199] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.199] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event14)
[    29.199] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.199] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.199] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event5)
[    29.199] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.199] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus WMI hotkeys'
[    29.200] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event5 13:69 fd 32 paused 0
[    29.200] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[    29.200] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    29.200] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.201] (II) event5  - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.201] (II) event5  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[    29.201] (II) event5  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
[    29.201] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input8/event5"
[    29.201] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    29.201] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.201] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.201] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.201] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.202] (II) event5  - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.202] (II) event5  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[    29.202] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[    29.202] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    29.202] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    29.203] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event4 13:68 fd 33 paused 0
[    29.203] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    29.203] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    29.203] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[    29.657] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.657] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    29.658] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[    29.658] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[    29.658] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[    29.658] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.658] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us,ru"
[    29.658] (**) Option "xkb_variant" ","
[    29.658] (**) Option "xkb_options" "grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll"
[    29.660] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    29.660] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[    29.857] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SDC", prod id 17227
[    29.857] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[    29.857] (II) intel(0): Modeline "3840x2160"x0.0  526.91  3840 3888 3920 3956  2160 2162 2167 2220 -hsync -vsync (133.2 kHz eP)
[    30.346] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 8x8
[    30.353] (II) intel(0): resizing framebuffer to 3840x2160
[    30.366] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 3840x2160@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
```

The question is: "What I've missed in xorg/nvidia/dm configuration so  xorg don't recognize nvidia gpu"?

Comment: `(WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support` suggests your kernel configuration may have missed `CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y`.

Comment: @telcoM acutally, I have `CONFIG_VGA_ARB=y` in `/boot/config-5.0.0-13-generic`(and in `/boot/config-4.18.0-17-generic` as well).

Comment: @DanilаMaslennikov did you ever make any progress?

Comment: @AurélienGasser Unfortunately, I didn't. I ended up with switching to different distro (Manjaro) and it worked.